# How to aggregate string values with common keys in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Here is a minimal example of the input Pandas Dataframe:

```
  |-----+---------|
  | key | Value   |
  |-----+---------|
  |  A  | alpha   |
  |  B  | beta    |
  |  B  | gamma   |
  |  B  | delta   |
  |  C  | delta   |
  |  D  | delta   |
  |  D  | epsilon |
  |-----+---------|
```

Here is the output I'd like to generate with Pandas

```
  |-----+------------------|
  | key | Value            |
  |-----+------------------|
  |  A  | alpha            |
  |  B  | beta gamma delta |
  |  B  | beta gamma delta |
  |  B  | beta gamma delta |
  |  C  | delta            |
  |  D  | delta epsilon    |
  |  D  | delta epsilon    |
  |-----+------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `groupby()` and `transform()`:

```
df['Value']=df.groupby('key')['Value'].transform(' '.join)
```

OR

via `groupby()`,`agg()` and `map()`:

```
df['Value']=df['key'].map(df.groupby('key')['Value'].agg(set).str.join(' '))
```

output of `df`:

```
   key  Value
0   A   alpha
1   B   beta gamma delta
2   B   beta gamma delta
3   B   beta gamma delta
4   C   delta
5   D   delta epsilon
6   D   delta epsilon
```

**Update:**

use `drop_duplicates()` to removes duplicated values:

```
out=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['key','Value']).groupby('key')['Value'].transform(' '.join)
```

Comment: My bad, I changed 'ID' to 'key' in the question. That's why one 'ID' remains in your answer. Please edit `df['Value']=df['key'].map(df.groupby('ID')['Value'].agg(' '.join))` to `df['Value']=df['key'].map(df.groupby('key')['Value'].agg(' '.join))`

Comment: @crocefisso updated answer.....kindly have a look and thnx for noticing ***:)***

Comment: Unexpectedly in my output, I have lines like "beta gamma gamma gamma delta" do you know how I can get "beta gamma delta" instead?

Comment: @crocefisso updated answer....kindly check(2nd method bcz 1st method doesn't work in that case) ***:)***

Comment: Both methods return the same results with 1743 for `len(df['Value'].unique())`. Where I didn't expect more than 20.

Comment: @crocefisso If I understand correctly then....updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: By bad, I didn't reset the variables. It works indeed! Thanks!